# Lambda calculus application

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have a function application:

```
E1 E2
```

Can someone please show me an example, how to execute function?

Comment: It seems you are having trouble with some basic concepts, I recommend looking at the first chapter of [Lambda-Calculus and Combinators: An Introduction](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521898850), it has lots of examples.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "executing a function."

Comment: I mean apply E1 to E2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have at least one abstraction just go on $\beta$-reducing. It just works like taking an input $x$ and computing $f(x)$.

$$ (\lambda x. x + 1)1$$ 
is an application.

$$ [1/x](x + 1)$$
$$ (1+1) \rightarrow_\beta 2$$

Comment: If I do not have any abstraction?

Comment: @zero_coding Application can only be reduced when there's an abstraction on the left. If this happens nowhere in the whole lambda term, then the term is a normal form (has been already reduced as far as possible).